# UITextField isn't being set from a delegate method, but the same can be set from other methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, xcode4.5

In FirstViewController.h I have declared a delegate

```
id _delegate;

@property (nonatomic,strong) id _delegate;
-(void)startSampleProcess:(NSString *) arguement1;
```

In FirstViewController.m I have implemented startSampleProcess

```
-(void)startSampleProcess:(NSString *)arguement1{

[textField1 setText:@"rajesh"];//Setting SOME text Field
}
```

In CustomCell.m I have declared and used the delegate object in one of the TextField delegate methods

```
 -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

     sampleProtocol  = [[iOSFirstViewController alloc]init];
     sampleProtocol._delegate = self;

     [sampleProtocol startSampleProcess:@"MASTER COMPUTER"];
      NSLog(@"textFieldDidEndEditing");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this  Declaring protocol

```
@protocol SampleProcessDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)startSampleProcess:(NSString *) arguement1;
@end
@interface PocketBugzDropDownView : UIView<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{

    id <SampleProcessDelegate>      delegate;
}
@property(nonatomic)id<SampleProcessDelegate>       delegate;
@end
```

in .m file

```
@synthesize delegate

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

 [self.delegate startSampleProcess:textFiled.text];
}
```

if access that delegate any filedecleare delegate in .h file

```
sampleProtocol  = [[iOSFirstViewController alloc]init];
     sampleProtocol._delegate = self;
-(void)startSampleProcess:(NSString *) arguement1
{
  nslog(@"%@",arguement1);
}
```